# Attending a conference with an abstract accepted but without a full paper submitted

Tags: conference, abstract

I'm a Ph.D. and my abstract has been selected for an international conference. This is my first international occasion.
I have to pay now the fee as an author and I have little time to submit the full paper before the deadline for the future proceedings. (I'm also evaluating to take mode time and completing it in the future, for a journal) 
I'm here cause in this call there is the option for not presenting the full paper but to register as an author the same. I have no experiences in this matter so here is my question: what happens if I decide to not submit the full paper? For me would be very important to present my work in progress at the conference and, maybe, one day publish the full paper in a journal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Noting your field would be helpful - as the conventions for how serious a faux-pas it would be likely depends on your field. (In my field, while many established  conference will publish proceedings, it wouldn't be very unusual for attendees to not submit  while still giving their talk or presenting a poster on on-going work) - but I gather that it is quite different in other fields.

Comment: This might sound like a crazy idea, but have you thought about asking your mentor/supervisor/colleagues, who know your work and the conference you are talking about? And what's a conference where you have to pay as an author? Sound's like a ripoff. On proper conferences, every participant has to pay, whether he is presenting or not.

Comment: @Karl: "And what's a conference where you have to pay as an author? Sound's like a ripoff. On proper conferences, every participant has to pay, whether he is presenting or not." - it's not clear from the question whether only authors have to pay, or whether the OP is only going to attend if/because they are an author.

Comment: I do not believe this question can be answered well without the clarifying information that was requested by the commenters, and the OP appears to have abandoned the question.  I have thus voted to close as "unclear".

Comment: Tnx to everybody answered. It seems that after a positive feedback of my full paper from a double-blind peer review of the full paper I will be able to speak at the conference